# CherryPy allways decodes Basic Auth with ISO-8859-1

Tags: python, character-encoding, cherrypy, basic-authentication

<strike>Is there a way to configure cherrypy to correctly decode utf-8 encoded authentication strings?</strike>

## Update

It's know limitation documented in [issue #1680](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/1680).

Until the issue is resolved, CherryPy will not recognize UTF-8 encoded Basic-Auth Data.

## Original Problem

I have trouble using basic-auth with name/passwords using umlaut characters. There seem to be no way to either bring the http-client to issue ISO-8859-1 (which cherrypy would unterstand) name:password or to configure cherrypy to decode the authentication string using utf-8.

Using Python 3.6 and CherryPy 13.1.0:

```
import cherrypy

class SimpleWebpage(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "<html><head></head><body>Authenticated</body></html>"

def dummy_validate(realm, username, password):
    print("realm: {realm!r}, username: {username!r}, password: {password!r}".format_map(locals()))
    return True

cherrypy.tree.mount(SimpleWebpage(), '/',
                    {'/': {'tools.auth_basic.checkpassword': dummy_validate,
                           'tools.auth_basic.on': True,
                           'tools.auth_basic.realm': 'MY_REALM',}})

cherrypy.config.update({'tools.sessions.on': True,})

cherrypy.engine.autoreload.unsubscribe()
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Calling curl with the following arguments:

```
curl -u 'Céline:motörhead' -i -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

Will give the following output from the cherrypy console:

```
[28/Dec/2017:15:52:57] ENGINE Bus STARTING
[28/Dec/2017:15:52:57] ENGINE Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080
[28/Dec/2017:15:52:57] ENGINE Bus STARTED
realm: 'MY_REALM', username: 'CÃ©line', password: 'motÃ¶rhead'
127.0.0.1 - C\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9line [28/Dec/2017:15:53:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 52 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))"
```

Tested with curl 7.56.1 (i686-pc-cygwin) on cygwin and curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) on redhat6. I've also tested it with google-chrome 63.0.3239.108 with the exact same results.

## [Kludge](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge)

```
def decode_utf8(s):
    s_bytes = bytes([ord(c) for c in s])
    return s_bytes.decode('utf-8')

def dummy_validate(realm, username, password):
    username = decode_utf8(username)
    password = decode_utf8(password)
    print("realm: {realm!r}, username: {username!r}, password: {password!r}".format_map(locals()))
    return True
```

Using this code will gives me correct results with google-chrome and curl. But it won't work with (as an example) Firefox 57.0.2 (32-Bit) on Windows 10 which sends ISO-8851-15 encoded string.

Also this doesn't fix the `cherrypy.request.login` value.

Comment: Hi, please file an issue in the github repo, so that it could be sorted out in the framework itself. There was lots of Unicode-unfriendly stuff in the codebase, which got fixed over time, but there's still a room for improvement. https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/new

Comment: @webKnjaZ Okay, I'm on it. Will link the issue as soon I've posted it there. It seems bugs are **not** offtopic at stackoverflow.

Comment: You're right. It's not offtopic here, but still needs to be tracked in ustream as it might influence the fix process.

Comment: And it's my personal wish, because I don't always track SO.

Comment: Ref: https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/1680

Comment: @webKnjaZ Sorry for the confusion. I was comparing stackoverflow with askubuntu: On askubuntu bugs are offtopic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update (22nd of April, 2018):

Since [CherryPy v14.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/CherryPy/14.2.0/) `auth_basic` and `auth_digest` tools support [RFC 7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617) to the extent supported by HTTP clients (browsers), which tend to send corrupted data in some cases.

#### Old answer:

As [@webKnjaZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595220/webknjaz) has approved in the comments, this is a bug which either needs to be resolve within CherryPy or cheroot.

I consider the question as answered. Further progress the concerning bug can be tracked on the corresponding [CherryPy-Issue](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/1680).